# Find new ID for Database by checking lowest number in value of from SQL returned array

Tags: php, sql

So I was trying to make a "create new user" function in PHP which should basically check in the database which is the lowest possible ID to assign to that new user. But I have now tried around with so many different methods and they all do not work as they should. Here is my current version:

```
function newUser($connection) {
    $notNewId = sqlsrv_query ($connection, "SELECT id FROM users"); //get id from users table
    while($notNewId2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array ($notNewId)) {
        for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeOf($notNewId2); $i++) { 
            foreach ($notNewId2 as $key => $value ) {
                if ($i != $value) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    $id = $i;
    return $id;
    }
}
```

the $connection is a element of type sqlsrv_connect.
as far as I can tell my current version should be able to read the ids and put them in an array, but from there on something went wrong. As well... I may have to sort the array after id, but I have no clue how to do that.

I would really appreciate any help, even if it's no actual code and just the logic explained, thx.

EDIT: Seems like it is not clear enough, what I want. My script should assign a new ID to the new row in the users table, if that is possible automatically somehow with SQL, then please explain to me how. (Right now ID is not a primary key, I will change that as soon as I can)
Taking the highest number and adding one is not enough (like when I have 0, 1, 2, 4 and 5, the new ID should be 3, not 6). But still thanks, I didn't knew about that MAX thing.

Comment: Why not just use an auto-increment ID column?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  Why does creating a new user depend on the ID values of existing users?  Are you just looking for `IDENTITY` in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `id` is your primary key and you're not trying to auto increment it in your `users` table, you can find the maximum value of it and add 1 in your SQL query. This mitigates the need for your nested for loops. Use `ISNULL` to check if that value is not null and default to 1 otherwise.

```
function newUser($connection) {
    $query = sqlsrv_query ($connection, "SELECT ISNULL(MAX(id)+1, 1) FROM users");
    return sqlsrv_fetch($query);
}
```

Comment: Careful if you want to later use that result for an insert. Any concurrent instance of your program could have read the same value. That eventually can, after the inserts, result in duplicate values -- in an ID column that's usually unwanted. Acquire a [write lock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html) before that select to lock it for other transactions. (And release it after the insert.)